# Variable that returns complete string inside list

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
topic = "test4"
topics = sns.get_all_topics()   
topicsList = topics['ListTopicsResponse']['ListTopicsResult']['Topics']
topicsListNames = [t['TopicArn'] for t in topicsList]
```

That returns a list:

```
[u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:10:test4', u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:11:test7']
```

What Im trying now is create a variable that returns the complete string relative to the `topic` variable.

I have the variable `topic = "test4"`, and I want to have a variable `topicResult` that returns `u'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:10:test4`.

The string relative to `topic` its not always in list 1st position.

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: So you always want to find the item(s) where `t['TopicArn'].endswith(topic)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
topicResult = " ".join([t['TopicArn'] for t in topicsList if t['TopicArn'].endswith(topic)])
```

This will check the strings in the list to see if the `topic` variable is the end of one of the strings. `" ".join()` gives you a string, but if you want to keep a list of the strings that end with `topic`, you can get rid of it. If `topic` won't always be at the end of the string, you can just check if `topic`is inside the string.

```
topicResult = " ".join([t['TopicArn'] for t in topicsList if topic in t['TopicArn']])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use intention lists, with a check statement in, but I think built-in filter will be faster:

```
topicsListNames = filter(lambda item: item['TopicArn'].endswith(topic), topicsList)
```

Basically, this line take the `topicsList`, then takes only the items `item` for which `item['TopicArn'].endswith(topic)` is True, ie. the items whose `'TopicArn'` element ends with the reference of the `topic` variable. Finally, all these "good" items are returned, and `topicsListNames` references them.